Linqpad 7 references missing from my machine when transfered to production environment with same Linqpad 7 configuration
I wrote my script in Linqpad 7 on my machine. All references and everything is intact. But when I move this script to my production environment, the script misses all the references. Even in my production environment, I have same Linqpad 7 installed. Why this might be happening?
I tried checking the query properties both Additional references and namespace imports along with the versions, Everything matches!
